# angular ui router- urlRouterProvider otherwise redirection

Tags: angular-ui-router

It seems like the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/') only works for url which consist 1 segment only i.e abc.com/abcdefg will be redirected to abc.com/ if abcdefg is not defined as part of the state.

But something like abc.com/abc/abcd or abc.com/abc/abcd/abcde/abcdef and so on (url with more than 1 segments ) won't get redirected to abc.com/

Does the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise only works on url with 1 segment only?

Comment: Please edit and clarify your question, it is hard to understand

Comment: It should work for abc.com/abc/abcd/abcde/abcdef, have you debug it?

Comment: @huanfeng no luck on that, as the error message printed out on the console weren't very helpful

Comment: @huanfeng managed to resolved this issue. it was a false positive as the issue is on my laravel side. thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to resolved this issue. it was a false positive as the issue is on my laravel side. thanks everybody